# Javascript: How to automatically select http/https and ws/wss?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently developing a small web app and I'm using axios and websockets for dynamically fetching data from the backend. Up until now, I was using `"http://" + window.location.host` or `"ws://" + window.location.host` to create relative urls for my backend, so that both frontend and backend could use the correct api in development and deployment. This setup worked perfectly until I added https to the backend server. Now I need different url prefixes (`http://` and `ws://` vs `https://` and `wss://`) for development and deployment. Is there any way to automatically select the right protocol for each environment?

Comment: Just use `window.location` for http (covers both cases) and `window.location.replace(/^https(.*)/, 'wss$1').replace(/^http(.*)/, 'ws$1');` for websocket.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL

Comment: @epascarello Protocol-relative URLs don't work when referring to a websocket url from a web page.

Comment: @Bergi but works fine for the http/https ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
var httpProtocol = 'http://'; 
var wsProtocol = 'ws://';
if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
    httpProtocol = 'https://';
    wsProtocol = 'wss://';
}
```

`window.location.protocol` seems to be what I'm looking for to switch between TLS and non TLS communication.